# с++ Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, sfml, build-error

Ошибка

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ ""class std::list<class Object *,class std::allocator<class Object *> > objects" (?objects@@3V?$list@PAVObject@@V?$allocator@PAVObject@@@std@@@std@@A)"    TopDownShooter  D:\Games\MyGames\TopDownShooter\TopDownShooter\Game.obj 1
```

Global.h

```
#ifndef Global_h
#define Global_h
#include "Object.h"
extern std::list<Object*>  objects;
#endif
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "Global.h"
#include "Object.h"
using namespace sf;
void Game::Start(RenderWindow &window)
{

    std::cout << objects.size() << "\n";
    Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromFile("tex.png");
    Sprite spr;
    spr.setTexture(tex);
    Object obj(spr);
    objects.push_back(&obj);
    std::cout<< objects.size() << "\n";

}

void Game::Update(RenderWindow &window)
{

    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }



}
```

Comment: Ну и где ваше *определение* `std::list<Object*>  objects;`?

Comment: @Harry в global.h

Comment: @Harry понял в чём моя ошибка, спасибо